# How would I avoid using a goto statement here?

Tags: c

I am pretty new to programming in C and I am making a simple dice based game. I have all the other logic working but I am having trouble seeing how to avoid a goto statement. Basically the player starts with 50 dollars as their balance and the program asks for a bet, then dice are rolled and depending on what the result of the roll is different things happen. The main issue is when the result happens the user is asked if they want to play again, if they say no then I just exit but if they say yes I need to go back to the start and ask for a bet again.

```
int main()
{

        START:

    if (FirstRun == 0)
    {
        printf("Your starting balance is $%.2f", Balance);
    }
    if (FirstRun > 0)
    {
        printf("Your new balance is $%.2f", Balance);
    }
    if (Balance <= 0)
    {
        printf("Sorry you are out of money!");
        exit(0);
    }

    do
    {
        ValidBet = 0;
        printf("\nPlease enter your bet:");
        scanf("%lf", &Bet);

        if ((Bet > Balance) || (Bet < 0))
        {
            printf("Your bet is invalid, try again.");
        }
        else 
        {
            ValidBet = 1;
        }
    } while (ValidBet == 0);

    ThrowDicePair();
    printf("DICE #1 WAS %d", SumOfThrows);

    if (SumOfThrows == 7 || SumOfThrows == 11)
    {
        Balance += Bet;
        printf("You win! Would you like to play again? [y/n]");
        C = getch();
        if (C == 'y')
        {
            FirstRun++;
            goto START;
        }
        else if (C == 'n')
        {
            printf("Thanks for playing");
            exit(0);
        }

}
```

Comment: *"I am pretty new to programming in C"* - And whatever resource you are learning from covered `goto` before any loop statements? That's a red flag.

Comment: How do you repeatedly ask for a valid bet? Maybe you could re-use ideas from that part of the code?

Comment: @StoryTeller To be fair, there is a `do-while loop` in the code.

Comment: Wrap everything in an endless loop, `for (;;) { ... }`

Comment: @StoryTeller Well I am actully taking a class in C programming and the teacher just briefly covered gotos, but I already know how for,while, do-while etc. work I am just confused on how to use them here

Comment: What is more worrying, is that none of the variables used are declared any where in the code

Comment: @ChrisTurner I didn't include that in this section of my code, they are declared in the full code

Comment: @Kelas3 your case is very simple, only one case where you reloop and all other you return/exit, so few modifications to do, see my answer. I encourage you to not make a version with label/goto to remove them after but directly use a version without, just do like if _goto_ does not exist  ;-)

Comment: The function: `getch()` is not portable.  Suggest using `getchar()` instead

Comment: When posting code, it is highly preferred to post code that cleanly compiles (unless the question is about the compiling)  The posted code does not compile!  it is missing the needed `#include` statements for the needed header files.  Please don't make us guess as to which header files your code actually includes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just put all in a `for(;;)` loop; the *goto* will be the case where you reloop, in the other cases add a `return 0;`(or `exit(0);` as you prefer and already use in some cases)

```
int main()
{

  for (;;) { /* ADDED  */
    if (FirstRun == 0)
    {
        printf("Your starting balance is $%.2f", Balance);
    }
    if (FirstRun > 0)
    {
        printf("Your new balance is $%.2f", Balance);
    }
    if (Balance <= 0)
    {
        printf("Sorry you are out of money!");
        exit(0);
    }

    do
    {
        ValidBet = 0;
        printf("\nPlease enter your bet:");
        scanf("%lf", &Bet);

        if ((Bet > Balance) || (Bet < 0))
        {
            printf("Your bet is invalid, try again.");
        }
        else 
        {
            ValidBet = 1;
        }
    } while (ValidBet == 0);

    ThrowDicePair();
    printf("DICE #1 WAS %d", SumOfThrows);

    if (SumOfThrows == 7 || SumOfThrows == 11)
    {
        Balance += Bet;
        printf("You win! Would you like to play again? [y/n]");
        C = getch();
        if (C == 'y')
        {
            FirstRun++;
            /* goto START; removed */
        }
        else if (C == 'n')
        {
            printf("Thanks for playing");
            exit(0);
        }
        else /* ADDED */
          return 0; /* ADDED */
    }
    else /* ADDED */
      return 0; /* ADDED */
  } /* ADDED  */
}
```

In more complicated/nested cases you can use a *continue* to reloop, but here this is useless

Comment: I personally prefer while(1) over for(;;), but it is a matter of taste.

Comment: @machine_1 at that level this is very _taste and color_ ^^

Comment: Most of the printing statements would benefit from a newline at the end (the exception is the 'play again' prompt, which would benefit from a space at the end).  Why `return 0;` instead of `exit(0);` in the added lines — or why `exit(0)` instead of `return 0;` where it is used?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I used `return 0;` to do exactly like the original code, that return being implicit

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to ensure the person plays the game at least one time before electing to quit, a do...while loop would work just fine. Just start the loop where you want to iterate back to, i.e. your START label and then take the input into C at the end of your loop conditioning on whether or not your input is equal to 'n' or 'N'.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main() {
    while (1) { /* ADDED  */
        if (FirstRun == 0) {
            printf("Your starting balance is $%.2f", Balance);
        }
        if (FirstRun > 0) {
            printf("Your new balance is $%.2f", Balance);
        }
        if (Balance <= 0) {
            printf("Sorry you are out of money!");
            exit(0);
        }

        do {
            ValidBet = 0;
            printf("\nPlease enter your bet:");
            scanf("%lf", &Bet);

            if ((Bet > Balance) || (Bet < 0)) {
                printf("Your bet is invalid, try again.");
            } else {
                ValidBet = 1;
            }
        } while (ValidBet == 0);

        ThrowDicePair();
        printf("DICE #1 WAS %d", SumOfThrows);

        if (SumOfThrows == 7 || SumOfThrows == 11) {
            Balance += Bet;
            printf("You win! Would you like to play again? [y/n]");
            C = getch();
            if (C == 'y') {
                FirstRun++;
                continue; /* ADDED  */
            } else if (C == 'n') {
                printf("Thanks for playing");
                exit(0);
            }
        }
        break; /* ADDED  */
    }
}
```